# PHP - prevent users from play around with url GET variables

Tags: php

I have the following url

```
localhost/url/index.php?user_id=3
```

what is the best way to prevent site users from doing something like ?user_id=whatever,  and i really dont want to use POST for some reasons in this case

Comment: Does it matter if you prevent SQL injection, validate or cast your variables?

Comment: no actually all i want is something like user_id=dfsdfsf and in my index.php i turn this (dfsdfsf) into (3)

Comment: You could put it in `$_SESSION` instead, but the point of parameters is they change, if you don't want it to change then don't put it in the url.

Comment: You simply can't, the user can do whatever he wants with the URL and there is nothing you can do about it. Validate and filter data in your server instead.

Comment: $_COOKIES['user_id'] = 10 or

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 10

Comment: My bad, forgot to put the underscores, lost my touch with PHP

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't shoot querystring parameters ($_GET) directly into the database without some sort
   of sanitizing (suggestion: use stored procedures).
2. Use some kind of authorization to protect resources
   the user shouldn't be able to access.
3. Display a nice error page.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use:

`$_COOKIE['user_id'] = 10` or

`$_SESSION['user_id'] = 10`

In my opinion, Session would be better as you can log them out after every session of theirs and as said by @mehdi, it cant be edited by users, unlike cookies.

to use session, you will need `session_start();` in front of every file

Comment: BTW cookies can still be changed by the user.

Comment: Yeah that's why I prefer Session

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all that has been mentioned, since you are building the correct query string, etc. then include a hash of some sort that is a hash of all of the bits of data.  The same applies when storing data on the client's machine as a cookie...

When you receive the GET (or read the cookie), use the data in it to re-calculate the hash, and stop/redirect/error out if the data no longer validates the hash check.  When you do this, use some server-side salt that isn't displayed in the URL or in web page source, etc.

```
$user=3;
$urlGet="?userid=".$user."&uuid=".sha1($user."salt");
print("<a href='/index.php".$urlGet."'>click</a>");
```

Then when the link is clicked...

```
if(sha1($_GET['userid']."salt")!==$_GET['uuid']){
  header("location: /index.php");
  exit'
}
```